# modprobe error: could not insert 'ext3': Device or resource busy

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, ext3

I'm working towards understanding the ext3 file system. i have added printk statements into the files inside kernel source files of ext3, to see how things get executed by watching the kernel buffer messages (dmesg). I have followed the steps given in this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module . i am using following commands to build ext3 as a module to experiment on it by loading and unloading it using modprobe.

The commands are:

```
cd $HOME/linux-3.12.36/
make oldconfig     # copy old .config to ./
vi .config         # i have made CONFIG_EXT3_FS=m
make prepare
make modules_prepare
make SUBDIRS=scripts/mod
make SUBDIRS=fs/ext3 modules
# Then I created 'ext3' directory in /lib/modules/3.12.36/kernel/fs, which was not there earlier.
cp fs/ext3/ext3.ko /lib/modules/3.12.36/kernel/fs/ext3/
depmod
modprobe ext3
```

all executes ok... except the last statement which gives the error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ext3': Device or resource busy.
```

my lsmod result in case helpfull:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ums_realtek            18045  0 
usb_storage            62230  1 ums_realtek
auth_rpcgss            59261  0 
rfcomm                 69078  0 
bnep                   19704  2 
bluetooth             372312  10 bnep,rfcomm
sunrpc                284347  2 auth_rpcgss
arc4                   12608  2 
iwldvm                236564  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     41149  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    56979  1 
mac80211              607387  1 iwldvm
snd_hda_intel          56546  3 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
i915                  711131  8 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102042  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
iwlwifi               165575  1 iwldvm
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
parport_pc             32741  0 
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
uvcvideo               80843  0 
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
snd_timer              29427  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
cfg80211              483503  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
videobuf2_core         40625  1 uvcvideo
ppdev                  17635  0 
snd                    69274  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
intel_powerclamp       14727  0 
drm_kms_helper         52758  1 i915
videodev              134093  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
drm                   297924  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
lp                     17759  0 
dell_laptop            17369  0 
dcdbas                 14888  1 dell_laptop
dell_wmi               12681  0 
joydev                 17393  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
coretemp               13435  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
shpchp                 37047  0 
mei_me                 18437  0 
kvm_intel             143006  0 
mei                    78023  1 mei_me
lpc_ich                21093  0 
parport                42313  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
serio_raw              13483  0 
kvm                   445551  1 kvm_intel
intel_ips              18484  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
wmi                    19193  1 dell_wmi
video                  19058  1 i915
psmouse               106319  0 
ahci                   29929  5 
atl1c                  46050  0 
libahci                32009  1 ahci
```

after observing lsmod you can see that there is no ext3 or jbd module. What am i missing here or why else there is no ext3 module. yet i have installed my operating system on a drive partitioned with ext3.

i have unloaded the ext3 module for inserting my own, by typing:

```
modprobe -r ext3
```

and then,

```
modeprobe ext3
```

But still the error persists. Please help me to solve the **modprobe** problem.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: What is `dmesg` output after `modprobe` failed? It seems that you compile `ext3` as module(CONFIG_EXT3_FS=m), while the same is already compiled as in-core (CONFIG_EXT3_FS=y). These may conflict, e.g., about filesystem name(both use "ext3").

Comment: Yes ext3 is compiled as CONFIG_EXT3_FS=y. I should have done it as 'm', i guess. But doesn't modprobe -r ext3 remove it. So that I can put mine. But it doesn't work even by removing ext3.

Comment: For remove driver compiled into kernel, changing configuration and building new module are not sufficient. You need to rebuild whole kernel with new configuration, reinstall it(kernel) and restart system for load new kernel.

Comment: Thank You sir. It seems I have no other option but to compile the whole kernel again with the 'm' option. Please suggest if there is any solution, without compiling the whole kernel again.

Comment: There is no other way to remove driver compiled into kernel. But rebuilding kernel in you case will be relatively fast: kernel build system uses `make` efficiently.